Windows service exe throwing error "Breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been added for the documents." on vs 2022
I am developing a Windows service in c#, .exe I created using building the executable in release mode. The service runs correctly when started, but I encounter an issue when attempting to debug it. When I attach the process from the debug tab, I receive the message: "Breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."
Could you help me understand the reason for this issue and how to resolve it?
Despite the .pdb file being created in the release folder, I am still unable to debug, and breakpoints are not being hit. When I attach the process from the debug tab, I receive the message: "Breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."
Could you help me understand the reason for this issue and how to resolve it, as I am new to creating windows service?
